# Make a PowerPoint presentation using Python?

Tags: python, powerpoint

So I have a collection of close to 90 photographs along with a caption and the date stored in a text file. The images are of variable sizes and I would like to automate the procedure of converting this data into a PowerPoint presentation, with one picture on one slide along with its date and caption as the Title. Any reliable methods present?

Comment: Try [python-pptx](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-pptx). However, I would advise outputting HTML code for something like [Bespoke.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/bespoke.js/), which, IMO, would be somewhat easier.

Comment: ....if you know how to LaTeX, it might be easier to just use beamer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check out the [`python-pptx`](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library. Its useful for creating and updating PowerPoint `.pptx` files.

Also for some quick examples in `python-pptx` with screenshots, you can check this [link](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart.html).

Comment: this is good for .pptx files . but how to do this for .ppt file

Answer (score 6):

Another approach is to automate powerpoint through win32com. I have succesfully done this to augenerate presentations with lots of images following the instructions at http://www.s-anand.net/blog/automating-powerpoint-with-python/ .